# Windows 8.1 hibernation partition is 100+ gigs, physical memory is 32 gigs?

Tags: memory, windows-8.1, hibernate, disk-management

I have a 480 gig SSD as my OS drive. I have a usable partition of 345 gigs, which seems pretty small. According to Disk Manager I have a 101.36 gig partition for hibernation. I did some googling and it sounds like the hibernation partition is supposed to be the size of the amount of physical memory in the system, to allow for a memory dump when the machine goes into hibernation. I've only got 32 gigs. What is the other 69 gigs doing? I'd like it if i could use it. I can't find a way to resize the partition. Help?

Here's a screencap of my Disk Management if it offers any info.

[image]

Comment: Just out of interest do you use hibernation at all?

Comment: When I'm done with the computer I use "shutdown", but based on googling I was under the impression that Windows 8's ability to boot quickly (including after shutdown) was dependent on having that hibernate partition there.

Comment: Is Intel Rapid Start installed? You could see an icon on tray.